# How to use Group By, but keep all other values in the column (in mysqli)

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Is it possible to use Group By, yet keep all of the other associated values from the columns ?

```
month | date     | location
---------------------------
april  | 4/11/18 | US
april  | 4/16/18 | US
may    | 5/14/18 | Canada
june   | 6/05/18 | Canada
june   | 6/30/18 | US
```

Basically, I want to show distinct values for the month, but match the date underneath the respective month, and keep the other values.

```
april: 4/11/18 (US), 4/16/18 (US)
may: 5/14/18 (Canada)
june: 6/05/18 (Canada), 6/30/18 (US)
```

Here is the code I used:

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM events GROUP BY month");
```

This is just showing the distinct months.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you don't really want to `GROUP BY` at all.  This looks like more of a display/output issue.

Comment: @PatrickQ Check my answer. You can solve it with `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes, you _can_, but depending on the larger context of what's going on, I would't be shocked if having access to the date and country individually is valuable.  In which case, I would, personally, choose to select the records individually and then manipulate them for display as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**GROUP_CONCAT**](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)

[**SQL DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7c5c9/6)

```
 SELECT month,
        GROUP_CONCAT( date, '(', location, ')' ) as data
 FROM YourTable
 GROUP BY month
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| month |                                                data |
|-------|-----------------------------------------------------|
| april |     2018-04-11 00:00:00(US),2018-04-16 00:00:00(US) |
|  june | 2018-06-05 00:00:00(Canada),2018-06-30 00:00:00(US) |
|   may |                         2018-05-14 00:00:00(Canada) |
```

Comment: @scaisEdge I was still working on the demo, but beside give the link to the function not much to explain.

Comment: ..  ok  .. i have already upvoted .. mine was just a suggestion

Comment: @scaisEdge You know I have to be quick in case gordon is lurking around :P

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! I'm trying to put this statement in a php variable, and the GROUP_CONCAT isn't working - $query = ("SELECT month, GROUP_CONCAT(date) as data FROM events GROUP BY month");

Comment: First did you try the query in the database directly? and what mean isnt working?

Comment: I asked another question on this, as it seems unrelated to what I asked here, but seems your answer does the trick normally. Thanks!